# Issue: Cookies Not Sent to Local Node.js Server from Browse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I am a beginner in React and Node.js and have been experimenting with cookies for a server that I made. When I make a login request, it works as expected and sets the cookies that I send from my server to the browser. Of course, this was after I changed the domain name of the React app because, before that, it wasn't setting the cookies in the browser.

However, when I make a logout request from the browser, which should send the JWT cookies to the server, and the server looks for the user and clears the cookies from the JWT cookies, the cookies are not sent in the request (meaning the request does not include any cookies).

Here is some of the console.log output of req:

```
secret: undefined,
  cookies: [Object: null prototype] {},
  signedCookies: [Object: null prototype] {},
  body: {},
  _body: true,
  length: undefined,
  route: Route { path: '/', stack: [ [Layer] ], methods: { post: true } },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kHeaders)]: {
    host: 'localhost:5000',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'content-length': '2',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Opera";v="105", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"',
    accept: 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/105.0.0.0',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    origin: 'http://mydomain.local:3000',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    referer: 'http://mydomain.local:3000/',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
  },
  [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 34,
  [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
  [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
}
[Object: null prototype] {}
no cookies
[Object: null prototype] {}
no cookies
```

I have tried many ways to solve the problem, but without success.

Here is my logout request:

```
const handelLogout = async () => {
try {
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/logout', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'credentials': 'Include'               }, body: JSON.stringify({}),           });

// Check for success status if (response.status === 204) { console.log('Logout failed');           } else { console.error('Logout failed');           }       } catch (err) { console.log(err);       }   }; and this my logout controller: const User = require('../model/Users') const handelLogout = async (req , res) => {

const cookies = await req.cookies

if (!cookies?.jwt) { res.status(204).json('no content'); return console.log('no cookies');} const refreshToken = cookies.jwt

const foundUser = await User.findOne({refreshToken}).exec() if(!foundUser) { res.clearCookie('jwt' , { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'None' }) res.status(204).json('no content') console.log('no user ')     }

foundUser.refreshToken = '' const result = await foundUser.save() res.clearCookie('jwt' , { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'None' }) res.status(204).json('no content') console.log('logut success'); }
```

and this my cors setting:

```
const corsOptions = {
origin: 'http://mydomain.local:3000', credentials: true, };

app.use(cors(corsOptions)); app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
```

If you know anything about it or if you want to know more details about it please let me know.

If you know anything about it or if you want to know more details, please let me know. And if you need more information about my code, I will provide it.

Thank you.

i have the cookies in browser ( i mean i can see them in dev mode in browser) i try to send this cookies to server

and i expecting the server receive this cookies and processing the logout

Answer (score 0):

I think you misplaced the credential option, it should be in the top level of option not header

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/logout', { method: 'POST', credentials: "include", headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, body: JSON.stringify({})});
```

See [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included)

Comment: firstly thank you but i try this also but the same thing happening again

Comment: @Mmmmmm may I suggest you try Axios instead of Fetch? I had the same issue before and using Axios with {withCredentials: true} fixes it for me.

Comment: i will try it and tell you if it work  or not thanks